# User Auth in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I started learning Django last week and I thought the best way is to just build an App. I'm stuck now with the User Auth module with my tests. Maybe someone could help me out: 
I want to model employees in the db and also put them in the User Auth model, so I build the model and after a few checks I want to add it to User.

```
class Employee(models.Model):

session = models.ForeignKey(
    'sessions.Session',
    verbose_name='Session',
    blank=True, null=True,
)
email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput()) #render_value=False
password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
workgroup = models.ForeignKey(Workgroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user_since = models.DateTimeField('Signed up since', default=timezone.now())
rights = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def clean_username(self): # check if username dos not exist before
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['email']) #get user from user model
    except User.DoesNotExist :
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

    raise ValidationError("this user exist already")

def clean(self): # check if password 1 and password2 match each other
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:#check if both pass first validation
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']: # check if they match each other
            raise ValidationError("passwords dont match each other")

    return self.cleaned_data

def dosave(self): # create new user
    new_user=User.objects.create_user(self.cleaned_data['username'],
                              self.cleaned_data['email'],
                              self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    new_user.save()
    return new_user
```

So, next I wrote a few tests, one of them as following:

```
myuser = Employee.objects.create(first_name='Annie',
                                     last_name='Levers', email='annielevers@test.com',
                                     region=mymun, workgroup=mygroup, user_since=timezone.now())
    self.assertEquals(
        str(myuser),
        'annielevers@test.com',
    )

    # Check user.auth db
    userpk = myuser.id
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=userpk)
    user.set_password('abcxyz123')
    user.save()
```

When I run this test, the python cannot find an entry for userpk in User but gives me a 404 object.

Any ideas? Thanks so much already!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom user model you should use AbstractBaseUser.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @Becher This. The model that is going to be used for auth should extend `AbstractBaseUser`, otherwise you are in for a lot of custom code and digging through source, and for no apparent gain in this case.